# Object size using IntelliJ community edition debugger

Tags: java, intellij-14

Do we have a way to find java object size using in IntelliJ community edition debugger?

With C/C++ we can use sizeof to find the size. Do we have something similar which I can run in IntelliJ community edition debugger.

I tried [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object) getObjectSize in the variable window but couldn't use it.